# Combining data from multiple workbooks into a single worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

My code is designed to allow the user to open multiple workbooks and take the data from each workbook copy it in to a new workbook and save that workbook in a designated location with a dynamic name.

My code is failing when the data that has been copied from the opened workbooks in to the new workbook.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub ConslidateWorkbooks()

Dim Filename As Variant, nw As Integer
Dim i As Integer, A() As Variant
Dim tWB As Workbook, aWB As Workbook, nWB As Workbook
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim strFullname As String

Set tWB = ThisWorkbook
strFullname = "G:\CMG\DCM\Operations\Monthly Cycle\Monthly Transaction Upload\" & Range("PB") & "\" & Format(Range("CurrentDate"), "yyyy") & "\Raw Files\" & "Raw File - " & Range("PB") & Format(Range("CurrentDate"), "mmddyy") & ".csv"


Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Filter(*.csv), *.csv", Title:="Open File(s)", MultiSelect:=True)

'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

nw = UBound(Filename)
ReDim A(nw)
    For i = 1 To nw
        Workbooks.Open Filename(i)
        Set aWB = ActiveWorkbook
        A(i) = aWB.Sheets(1).Range("A6:L" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
        aWB.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Next i

Set nWB = Workbooks.Add
nWB.Activate
nWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1:L" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(A)
nWB.SaveAs Filename:=strFullname, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True
nWB.Close

'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I am expecting the data from each workbook (my test case is 4 separate workbooks, each with 1 sheet, all with a different number of rows but the exact number of columns (A-L)) to be copied in to a single sheet of a newly created workbook (consecutively copied). 
I am receiving a

> Run Time Error 13 Type Mismatch

on the following line of code:

```
nWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1:L" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(A)
```

Comment: `A` is not a 2-d array but an array of 2-D arrays - you can't use `Transpose` here.  You will need to loop over A and place each contained 2-D array onto the destination worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Something more like this:

```
Sub ConslidateWorkbooks()

    Dim Filename As Variant, nw As Long
    Dim i As Long, A() As Variant
    Dim tWB As Workbook, aWB As Workbook, nWB As Workbook, wb As Workbook
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet, arr
    Dim strFullname As String

    Set tWB = ThisWorkbook

    'all the ranges here should have workbook/worksheet qualifiers...
    strFullname = "G:\CMG\DCM\Operations\Monthly Cycle\Monthly Transaction Upload\" & _
               Range("PB") & "\" & Format(Range("CurrentDate"), "yyyy") & "\Raw Files\" & _
               "Raw File - " & Range("PB") & Format(Range("CurrentDate"), "mmddyy") & ".csv"


    Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Filter(*.csv), *.csv", _
                                           Title:="Open File(s)", MultiSelect:=True)

    nw = UBound(Filename)
    ReDim A(1 To nw) 'specify lower bound

    For i = 1 To nw
        Set aWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename(i))
        With aWB.Sheets(1)
            A(i) = .Range("A6:L" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
            .Parent.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End With
    Next i

    Set nWB = Workbooks.Add()

    With nWB.Sheets(1)
        'loop over the A array, and add each contained array to the sheet
        For i = 1 To nw
            arr = A(i)
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize( _
                          UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr
        Next i
        .Rows(1).Delete 'remove empty first row
    End With

    nWB.SaveAs Filename:=strFullname, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True
    nWB.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of Deleting the first row, is it possible to add a header so that each column (A-L) has a header?

Comment: Yes, you could do that.